# i'm getting a "None is not callable" error while studyin an exercise on python

Tags: python

This is my very first question.
I have not programmed anything since sinclair's 48k times, and now i'm trying to learn python.

I have browsed other questions related to "None is not callable" but unfortunately I have not clarified anything.
I was trying to avoid this but... i need your help.

I am trying to understand list comprehension but when trying to do the exercise I get the following error on line 27. 'NoneType' object is not callable

```
new_node = None (d, self.root)
```

Maybe it has to do with the order in which I call the methods, but I don't see it ...
**Thanks for your attention and sorry again**.

v.

```
    class Node(object):

        def __init__(self, d, n=None):
            self.data = d
            self.next_node = n

        def get_next(self):
            return self.next_node

        def set_next(self, n):
            self.next_node = n

        def set_data(self, d):
            self.data = d




    class LinkedList(object):

        def __init__(self, r=None):
            self.root = r
            self.size = 0

        def get_size(self):
            return self.size

        def add(self, d):
            new_node = None (d, self.root)
            self.root = new_node
            self.size += 1

        def remove(self, d):
            this_node = self.root
            prev_node = None

            while this_node:
                if this_node.get_data() == d:
                    if prev_node:
                        prev_node.set_next(this_node.get_next())

                    else:
                        self.root = this_node.get_next()

                    self.size -= 1
                    return True

                else:
                    prev_node = this_node
                    this_node = this_node.get_next()

            return False



    lista = LinkedList()    
    lista.add(16)
    lista.add(23)
    lista.add(53)
    lista.remove(23)
```

Comment: you can't call `None`... it's that simple. what were you trying to do? run this in python: `None()`

Comment: What do you expect `new_node = None (d, self.root)` to do? What you *are telling* it to do is take the object `None`, then *call it* with the arguments `d` and `self.root`, just as if you had done `func(d, self.root)`. That is what the error is say, that `None` is not callable (like a function)

Comment: =( sorry! i see it now... its Node instead of None =( 

should i delete the question?

Comment: It happens to the best of us, no worries.

Comment: As an aside, don't write getters and setters in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a linked list, so shouldn't the line

```
new_node = None (d, self.root)
```

be

```
new_node = Node(d, self.root)
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Replace None with Node:

```py
        def add(self, d):
            new_node = Node(d, self.root)
            self.root = new_node
            self.size += 1
```